# $\left[\frac{\log( \log x / \log 2 )}{\log 2} \right] \ge \frac{\log_2 x}{\log 2}- \left( 1 + \frac{1}{\log 2} \right)$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

The following lower bound appears in the book 'Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory' by Gérald Tenenbaum in page 10.

$$\left[\frac{\log( \log x / \log 2 )}{\log 2} \right] \ge \frac{\log_2 x}{\log 2}- \left( 1 + \frac{1}{\log 2} \right)$$

Substituting $x = 2^{2^{100}}$ yields: $$100 \ge 2^{100}/ \log 2 -\left( 1 + \frac{1}{\log 2} \right)$$which is absurd.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Does $\log_2 x$ mean $\log\log x$ in this book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Notation section of Tenenbaum's book,
"Furthermore, we denote by $\log_k$ the $k$-fold iterated logarithm".
Then $\log_2 x$ means $\log\log x$.

Then
$$\frac{\log(\log x/\log2)}{\log2}=\frac{\log\log x-\log\log2}{\log2}
=\frac{\log_2x}{\log 2}-\frac{\log_22}{\log2}.$$
Therefore
$$\left[\frac{\log(\log x/\log2)}{\log2}\right]
\ge\frac{\log_2x}{\log 2}-\left(1+\frac{\log_22}{\log2}\right).$$
This is actually what Tenenbaum states (NB $\log_22\ne1$).

Comment: Gosh! I feel stupid! ~0~